# PHP: split / explode not returning delimiters in result array

Tags: php, regex

Current string: "m, d - y".

I want to split / explode it by d, m and y.

After processing I should get:

```
array[0] = "m";
array[1] = ", ";
array[2] = "d";
array[3] = " - ";
array[4] = "y";
```

How to do this? Split and explode are removing my delimiters from the returned array.

Comment: you should use `preg_match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the input according to the boundary which exists before (`d` or `m` or `y` ) or the boundary which exists after `d` or `m` or `y`

```
$str = "m, d - y";
$match = preg_split('~(?<=[dmy])(?!$)|(?<!^)(?=[dmy])~m', $str);
print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => m
    [1] => , 
    [2] => d
    [3] =>  - 
    [4] => y
)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=[dmy])` immediate look after to `[dmy]` and match `(?!$)` won't be followed by end of the line. This would avoid matching the boundary exists at the last.
- `(?=[dmy])` matches all the boundaries which exists before d or m or y but the match won't be at the start of aline.

Comment: I would suggest `preg_split` too but some explanation of the method would be useful.

Comment: @Avinash Raj Just one question, what if I would like to look for %m, instead of a single character like "m"?

Comment: just add `%` before the char class like `(?<=%[dmy])(?!$)|(?<!^)(?=%[dmy])`

Comment: @Avinash Raj Thanks, helped me understanding regexp a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all` and match the delimiters and those, except delimiters with any spaces surrounding them.

Use the regex `/[dmy]|\s*[^dmy]\s*/`

Answer (score 0):

`preg_split` supports the option `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` that includes captured part of the delimiter in the final result.

```
$result = preg_split('~([mdy])~', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` option, removes empty strings from the result array.

Answer (score 0):

Split and Explode are not meant to return the separator. I'd say best function to use here is preg_match:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php

So you can define bracketed groups of chars that should get "grep'd" into one item of the resulting array.

The basic idea for the pattern here is to alternate the same group of chars [-, ] with and without the negation ^. Please note that the char - needs an escape \ because of its special meaning in the character class [].

[edit: learned something today: preg_split has a cool option. Thanks to the others mentioning that. Here are now both solutions to compare.]

```
<?php

$input = "m, d - y";

preg_match ("/([^ ,\-]+)([,\- ]+)([^ ,\-]+)([,\- ]+)([^ ,\-]+)/", $input, $result);
$result2 = preg_split ("/([\-\s,]+)/", $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print ("<pre>");
var_dump ($result);
var_dump ($result2);
print ("</pre>");
```